# Java , tdd approach, IO operations

Tags: java, testing, io

I am training TDD approach, but I have a problem. How to test IO operations ? I used junit so far, but I read that it shouldn't be used to test with external sources ( databases, files ...), so what will be better ? Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

You can't test the internal working of those external sources, but you can check the results.

For example, writing to a file:

> Start test
>   Store data you want to write in a variable
>   Write data to file
>   Read file
>   Check if data is the same as the one you stored
>   End test

Testing is about verifying end results, so it's not necessarily a bad thing you "lose" sight of a part of the process. Generally you can assume external sources (libraries, IO..) are well tested.

Answer (score 1):

Change your API to be passed `InputStream` and/or `OutputStream` and have your jUnit code pass ByteArrayInputStream and `ByteArrayOutputStream`, which you can easily set up/read from.

Of course your production code would need to change to, but you can often achieve this through a simple refactoring; leaving the API as-is but having the public methods call the refactored method, for example:

Change

```
public void read(File file) {
    // do something with contents of file
}
```

To

```
public void read(File file) {
    read(new FileInputStream(file));
}

// test this method
public void read(InputStream inputStream) {
    // do something with contents of inputStream
}
```

Comment: +1. ByteArrayInputStream or TestClass.getResourceAsStream("somefile.dat") with data loaded from your test code jar file.